# Only Frontend is Working while deploying reactjs project while backend is not working on cyclic,sh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I deployed my react project on cyclic.sh but only frontend part was seen to be working not backend.
For eg- My login page is visible but i'm not able to log in.

1. Server.js -

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const colors = require('colors')
const path = require('path')
const connectDb = require('./config/connectDb')
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');


//config dot env file
dotenv.config();

//call db
connectDb()

//rest object
const app = express()

//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

//routes
/*app.use(
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    changeOrigin: true,
  }),
);*/

//app.use('/api/v1/users', require('./routes/userRoute'));
//user routes
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoute')
app.use(userRouter);

//transaction routes
const transactionRouter = require('./routes/transactionRoutes')
app.use(transactionRouter)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')))
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'))
})

//port
const PORT = 8080 || process.env.PORT

//listen server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

2)package.json -

```
{
  "name": "expense-tracker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\" "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

I tried deploying in different websites like vercel and netlify, over there i'm getting error of 404 page not found.